# Racket function that checks if an instance of a struct consists of certain values in DrRacket

Tags: struct, scheme, lisp, racket

Hi I'm trying to write a function in Racket (like Scheme/Lisp) to check if an instance of a struct based on time consists of only am/AM and not pm/PM.

Here are my attempts at checking to see if an instance of AM/PM is just "AM" or just "am" :

```
(define (isAM? AM/PM-meridiem)
  (if (or(equal? AM/PM-meridiem "AM")
         (equal? AM/PM-meridiem "am"))
      (#t))
  (else (#f)))

(define (time) (AM/PM 2 20 "am"))
         
 (define (isAM?2 time)
    (or (equal? (AM/PM-meridiem time) "AM")
        (equal? (AM/PM-meridiem time) "am")))

 (define (isAM?3 time)
    (or (equal? AM/PM-meridiem "AM")
        (equal? AM/PM-meridiem "am")))
```

Here's the two struct functions the isAM? function uses that I wrote:

```
#lang slideshow

(struct 24HourClock (hours minutes)
  #:transparent
  #:guard (lambda (hours minutes err_name)
    (if (not (and (>= hours 0) (< hours 24)))
     (error err_name "Bad hours")
    (if (not (and (>= minutes 0) (< minutes 60)))
     (error err_name "Bad minutes")
    (values hours minutes)))))

(struct AM/PM 24HourClock (meridiem)
  #:transparent
  #:guard (lambda (hours minutes meridiem err_name)
            (if (not(and(and(number? hours)(> hours 0)(<= hours 12)(number? minutes))))
                (error err_name "Hours must be between 1 and 12 : 0")
                    (if [not (and(string? meridiem)(or
                         (equal? meridiem "am")
                         (equal? meridiem "AM")
                         (equal? meridiem "pm")
                         (equal? meridiem "PM")))]                    
                    (error err_name "Invalid value for meridiem")
                    (values hours minutes meridiem)))))
```

Comment: The `#lang slideshow` looks very, very odd.

Comment: The `AM/PM-meridiem` selector is a procedure. You need to pass it an instance of your struct. (It looks like you skipped over the basics of structs and jumped directly to advanced features like guards.)

Comment: And `t3` causes an error because it has the wrong format according to your guard. If you want to get rid of that error, either change `"Am"` or the guard.

Comment: Apart from all the other problems you need to *seriously* rethink how this works.  Your `AM/PM` type is a subtype of your `24HourClock` type: that means that anything expecting a `24HourClock` may legitimately get  an `AM/PM`.  So consider this: `(24HourClock-hours (AM/PM 2 30 "pm"))`: oh dear.  A 12 hour clock is not, in fact, a subtype of a 24-hour clock as you have made it be, because its fields have different and incompatible semantics.

Comment: @molbdnilo yeah this was after one class of learning structs and we moved straight to guards and I'm just now learning Racket and functional lisp languages in general, I'm coming from a c++/java/python background

Comment: @ignisvolens yeah guess it's a bit weird, it's the assignment and these functions are specified (just not how to implement them). I basically just need to find if something is just AM/am, is that possible?

Comment: What about something like this: ```(define (isAM? AM/PM-meridiem) (if (or(equal? AM/PM-meridiem "AM") (equal? AM/PM-meridiem "am")) (#t)) (else (#f)))``` the issue though is it still doesn't work

Comment: Your AM/PM guard has an unnecessary `and` - your inner one has four arguments, which is fine, so the outer one will either do `(and #t)` or `(and #f)`, which are also formally fine, but pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're struggling with the fundamentals of syntax.

`(#t)` tries to use `#t` as a procedure, which it isn't.
(Parentheses are not block-structuring punctuation in the manner of curly braces in some other languages.)

And, as you seem to already know, a conditional does not have an "else" - the syntax is `(if condition true-expression false-expression)`, as you wrote in the guards.

And third, the parameter should be an instance of your struct - `AM/PM-meridiem` is the selector procedure you need to apply to it.

You also seem to have a habit of writing unnecessary conditionals with boolean values.
You should drop that habit in those other languages you are familiar with, as well.

Here is a corrected version:

```
(define (is-AM? time)
    (or (equal? (AM/PM-meridiem time) "AM")
        (equal? (AM/PM-meridiem time) "am")))
```

---

As an aside, the equivalent in C++ (or Java) would look something like this:

```
bool is_AM(AMPM time)
{
    return time.meridiem == "AM" || time.meridiem == "am";
}
```

and in Python,

```
def is_AM(time):
{
    return time.meridiem == "AM" or time.meridiem == "am";
}
```

Comment: oh I didn't realize equal? would automatically return a bool result :/ thanks!

Comment: Predicates that end with a question mark conventionally return only `#t` or `#f`.

Comment: The new issue is what goes in time? The AP/PM struct is this: ```(struct AM/PM 24HourClock (meridiem) #:guard (lambda (hours minutes meridiem err_name)``` so it needs hours, minutes, and meridiem, right?

Comment: sry about that I'm dumb and figured it out